# When to use Clustered Index on Foreign Key vs Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

I am trying to work out where is the best place to put clustered indices on child tables.

I have a SQL Server database that looks like the following:

`Journal`

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| `Id` | `bigint identity(1,1)` |
| `Name` | `nvarchar(300)` |
| ...others | ... |

`Note`

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| `Id` | `bigint identity(1,1)` |
| `JournalFk` | `bigint` |
| `NoteContent` | `nvarchar(max)` |
| ...others | ... |

Journals are created, then go through a workflow lasting a few days with Notes being added along the way, so if you were to look at the `JournalFk` column when ordering by `Id`, you'd notice it's *roughly* in order, but not exactly in order.

Most but not all queries done on `Note` are like "All notes for a Journal" i.e. lookups on the `JournalFk`. Occasionally, however, notes have to be accessed via the `Id` column to be updated.

These tables are high volume, with millions, sometimes tens of millions of rows, and sometimes a lot of additions in a short amount of time.

I have seen two kind of conflicting pieces of advice on clustered indices:

1. Only put clustered indices on columns which are sequentially added.
2. Put clustered indices on columns which are looked up the most.

Since `JournalFk` is *roughly* in order, my question is:

Should my clustered index on `Note` be:

- `(JournalFk, Id)` or
- `Id`

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you don't even need `note.id`, if you have another column, such as the note timestamp, to guarantee uniqueness (along with `journalfk`).

Comment: Hi mustaccio, thanks for your comment. Do you mean that `(JournalFk, timestamp)` would be the clustered index you'd go for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with nearly all things in SQL Server, "it depends". It especially depends on the queries in your workload and data model when it comes to indexing strategy.

If queries never access the `Notes` table by `Id` primary key column alone, this is the common data modeling mistake of introducing a needless single-column surrogate key on the many side of a one-to-many relationship. A single-column surrogate key might add value to avoid unwieldy composite keys when the table is also referenced by other foreign keys but that doesn't seem to be the case here from the information provided.

A better choice for the `Notes` table primary key may be a composite key consisting of the parent table primary key and the surrogate key (assuming you don't have other columns for a natural key). This way, the primary key can be clustered to optimize Journal table joins as well as retrieving Notes by `JournalFK`. Additional indexes may be needed to support the other queries you mentioned and those likely need `JournalFk` too, which will already be present in non-clustered leaf nodes as the row locator (clustered index key) and facilitate covering queries.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Journal (
     Id bigint identity(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Journal PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Name nvarchar(300) NOT NULL
    --etc.
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Notes (
     Id bigint identity(1,1)
    ,JournalFk bigint NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Notes_Journal FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Journal(Id)
    ,NoteContent varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_Notes PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (JournalFk, Id)
    --etc.
);
```

Keys should ideally be incremental but, IMHO, that consideration is secondary for most apps. Most importantly, rows most often accessed together should be co-located in the same page when possible and a composite clustered primary key index facilitates this.

EDIT:

From the additional information provided, notes may be subsequently updated and that is currently done using `Id` alone. If possible, it would be best to change the app to specify both columns of the proposed composite key. The relationship suggests a note has no logical context without the related JournalFk so I would expect the app code to already have the value. If that change is not feasible, create a unique constraint on `Id` to help optimize those updates.

Some fragmentation is expected and the cost of doing business. Regular index maintenance can mitigate fragmentation, perhaps with a reasonable fill factor. I wouldn't be overly concerned with it unless your actual workload proves otherwise. Again, "it depends".

Comment: Mr. Guzman, thank you so much for your insightful comment. I don't think replacing the key with a composite is possible because notes sometimes have to be updated and so are needed to be accessed by the `Id` on occasion. I will update my question.

Is index fragmentation a risk with the clustered index you suggest, due to the high volume?

Comment: @MarcC., I added to my question to help answer your follow-up.